# Can all null-homotopy be made differentiable on arbitrary metric space?

Tags: derivatives, metric-spaces, homotopy-theory

Let $M$ be a metric, and assume that it is simply connected. For a closed curve $f$, we define it to be differentiable iff for any $x$ then $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{d(f(x),f(x+h))}{h}$ exist, where we take $f$ to be extended into a periodic function with period $1$ for the sake of having both side when taking the derivative at the boundary.

The question is:

Given a closed curve $f$ that is differentiable. Does there always exist a null-homotopy of $f$ such that all curves along the homotopy process is differentiable.

I believe the answer to be no, but I am still unsure either way. Any helps would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "null-homotopy of f"? Homotopy to a constant map? But then just take f which is not null-homotopic. Also, think about M which is a fractal Jordan curve in the plane with the restricted metric, such that no arc in M is rectifyable.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, whether there is a homotopy from $f$ to a constant map such that every curve along the way is differentiable (by the above def of differentiable). I also notice I forgot to require that $f$ must be differentiable too. I will edit that. The simply connected requirement ensure that there are non-null-homotopic curve.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the simple connectivity assumption. The answer however is still negative: you have to make further assumptions to make it work, say that M is a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @studiosus:In that case, can you show me a counterexample then? I don't have good intuition for metric space that isn't a manifold, so that presumably might be why I am having trouble finding a counterexample. Thanks (also, make it an answer please)

Comment: I'm not sure, but what if we just let $M$ be the graph of a nowhere differentiable function and give it the induced Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the "snowflake" metric  $d(a,b)=|a-b|^\alpha$ on the closed unit  disk $D\subset \mathbb R^2$, where $\alpha \in(0,1)$ can be any fixed number.  Let this metric space be denoted by $X_1$, and its subset $\partial D\subset X_1$ by $Y_1$.  It is easy to see that $X_1$ contains no differentiable curves except constant ones, since differentiability with respect to its metric implies having zero derivative in the Euclidean sense.

Also consider the Euclidean (restriction) metric on the complement of open unit disk, $\overline{\mathbb R^2\setminus D}$. Let this metric space be denoted by $X_2$, and its subset $\partial D\subset X_2$ by $Y_2$.

The idea is to sew $X_1$ and $X_2$ along $\partial D$, thus obtaining a counterexample: $X_2$ contains differentiable closed curves which would have to pass through $X_1$ to be nullhomotoped.

Sewing is messy, but luckily it was already done in detail: see Theorem 1 in [A sewing problem in metric spaces](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol34/Haissinsky.html) by Haissinsky. 
It applies here with the sewing map $f:Y_1\to Y_2$ being the identity map (which is quasisymmetric, as required). The theorem produces a metric on  the quotient  $\widehat{X}=(X_1\sqcup X_2)/f$ which is locally bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the original metrics away from $\partial D$. This is the desired counterexample.